Is it possible to constrain droppable items React DND-Kit so they do not swap with previously disabled list items?
I'm trying to disable a person from reordering any list items once they have become disabled.
So it I have list and I disable the top three, you can no longer selector those items to reorder them (great), but you can still drop items which have not been disabled and they they will swap positions which any item which has been disabled. This is not good.
Is this a modification or way to stop this behavior.
The idea is once an item has been disabled in the list, then the user should should no longer be able to swap any item in that area of the list.
